# Describing nested classes in english

Tags: object-oriented-analysis

I am not sure I understand nested classes conceptually. A university class may have a student object inside it. That is composition. A university class may be a school, which is inheritance. But if I have a class defined within another class, how do I describe this relationship in a complete English statement? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.
Consider a Book which has properties like title, author, genre, year, publisher. Now publisher can be the inner class having properties like name, id, contact details etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: So a book class has a publisher as an object. That makes sense. I doesn't make sense to make a publisher class inside a book class, and that is different.